# Expanding Date Command inside single quotes in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, aws

I am new to linux. I am wondering why date command is not expanding inside single quotes.

so if i give command like below

```
d=$(date +%m%d) 
echo 'A1D$d'
```

Output is `A1D$d`

But If i give without quotes its working...

```
 d=$(date +%m%d) 
    echo A1D$d
```

Output is `A1D0603`

Can anyone pls help me in this

I need **date command to expand in the single quote** becoz....in **aws api commands** i need to used **date command inside the single quotes** like below

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D$(date +%m%d)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE
```

Comment: Nothing ever ever ever expands inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to command substitution. The variable `$d` has the same value in both cases.

But the singe quotes in `echo 'A1D$d'` prevent `$d` from being treated as a variable. Nothing you can do about that.

But if you have a long single-quoted string and need an expanded variable in between then you can interrupt the quotes:

```
echo 'thismustbequoted'"but here appears a ${variable}, yeah"'andmore singlequotedtext'
```

Comment: Can u pls explain,how to interrupt quotes in my case

Comment: @clarie `echo 'A1D'"$d"`